# Identifying the tangent space of a regular submanifold as a subspace

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The problem arises when I was doing exercise 11.1 in An Introduction to Manifolds by Tu.
Exercise 11.1 asks:

> For $p=(p^1,...,p^{n+1})\in S^n$, show that $X_p=\sum a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p\in T_p\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is tangent to $S^n$ at $p$ iff $\sum a^ip^i=0$.

My initial thought was that:

> Suppose $p^1\ne 0$. Let $f=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(x^i)^2-1$. We know that there exists a neighborhood $U\subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$ of $p$ on which $(f,x^2,...,x^{n+1})$ is a diffeomorphism (cf. regular level-set theorem) and $(U,f,x^2,...,x^{n+1})$ is a chart about $p$ on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. It is also an adapted chart of $S^n$, meaning $(U\cap S^n,x^2,...,x^{n+1})$ is a chart on $S^n$.

> Let $i:S^n\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ be the inclusion map. W.r.t. the above charts, $i_{*,p}$ has matrix representation $$\begin{pmatrix}0 &0 &... &0\\ 1 &0 &... &0\\ 0 &1 &... &0\\ ... &... &... &0\\ 0 &0 &... &1 \end{pmatrix}$$ since $f$ is constantly zero on $S^n$.

Now $T_pS^n$ is identified with the image of $i_{*,p}$, which is $span\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}|_p,...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{n+1}}|_p\}$, so $X_p$ is tangent to $S^n$ iff $a^1=0$, which is clearly incorrect.

My problem is that I do not understand why this (the above) does not work. I solved 11.1 later by noting $(i_{*,p}Y_p)f=0$ for all $Y_p\in T_pS^n$ together with an argument on dimensions.

Comment: I think I solved the issue. I will update later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to remark that $T_p\mathbb R^{n+1}$ has two bases:

$$
B_1=\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_p,...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{n+1}}|_p\},
B_2=\{\frac{\partial}{\partial f}|_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}|_p,...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{n+1}}|_p\}
$$

which are relative to the charts $$(\mathbb R^{n+1},\phi=id_{\mathbb R^{n+1}})=(\mathbb R^{n+1},x^1,...,x^{n+1})\,\,\, \text{and}\,\,\, (U,\psi)=(U,f,x^2,...,x^{n+1})$$ respectively.

**Short answer**: The $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ means completely different things when they are considered in the two different bases for $i=2,...,n+1$.

**Long answer**: To avoid confusion, let's write $\psi=(f,\bar x^2,...,\bar x^{n+1})$ and $B_2=\{\frac{\partial}{\partial f}|_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar x^2}|_p,...,\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^{n+1}}|_p\}$ where $x^i=\bar x^i$ as real-valued functions.

Note that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}|_pf=\frac{\partial (f\circ\phi^{-1})}{\partial r^2}|_{\phi(p)}=2x^2|_p=2p^2$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^2}|_pf=\frac{\partial(f\circ\psi^{-1})}{\partial r^2}|_{\psi(p)}=\frac{\partial(r^1\circ\psi\circ\psi^{-1})}{\partial r^2}|_{\psi(p)}=0$$
Hence they must be different if $p^2\ne 0$, and some $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^i}|_p$ must be different unless $p^1=1,0=p^2=...=p^{n+1}$.

Therefore, the issue in my initial thought is that $X_p=\sum a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ is a representation w.r.t. $B_1$, but my conclusion that "$X_p$ is tangent to $S^n$ iff $a^1=0$" should actually be phrased as: $X_p=b^1\frac{\partial}{\partial f}|_p+\sum_{i\ne 1}b^i\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar x^i}|_p$ (which is a representation of $X_p$ w.r.t. $B_2$) is tangent to $S^n$ iff $b^1=0$.

---

For a concrete example of the above observation, take $p=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})\in\mathbb R^2, f=x^2+y^2-1$. We have charts $(\mathbb R^2,x,y)$ and $(U,f,\bar y)$ where $y=\bar y$ as real-valued functions. Let $\psi=(f,\bar y)$. Its inverse is the map $(x,y)\mapsto (\pm\sqrt{x+1-y^2},y)$ where the sign depends on sign of $x$. With a bit computations one can find

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar y}|_p=-\frac{p_2}{p_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p, p=(p_1,p_2)
$$
which fits with our understanding of the tangent space of $S^1$ at $p$. Again, $y=\bar y$, and the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar y}|_p$ only stresses the fact that $y,\bar y$ are from different charts.

Comment: I did not notice this difference in meaning previously, nor did I see it in the textbook. I kinda think this is something important that students can easily get wrong on.